# connecting MaterialBottomTabNavigator and other screens which are not its part

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

So I am working on MaterialBottomTabNavigator and I have this small issue. I have 4 screens on it. The code is as shown below:

```
const bottomNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        home: {
            screen: HomeScreen,
            navigationOptions : {
                tabBarIcon: <Icon type="FontAwesome" name="home" style={{color:'#fff'}}  />, 
                title:'Home',
            }
        }


    trending: {
        screen: TrendingScreen,
        navigationOptions : {
            tabBarIcon: <Icon type="FontAwesome" name="fire" style={{color:'#fff'}}  />, 
            title:'Trending'
        }
    },
    profile: {
        screen: ProfileScreen,
        navigationOptions : {
            tabBarIcon: <Icon type="FontAwesome" name="id-badge" style={{color:'#fff'}}  />, 
            title:'Profile'
        }
    },

    settings: {
        screen:  SettingsScreen ,
        navigationOptions : {
            tabBarIcon: <Icon type="FontAwesome" name="cog" style={{color:'#fff'}}  />, 
            title:'Settings'
        }
    }
},

{
  initialRouteName: 'home',
  activeColor: '#f0edf6',
  inactiveColor: '#3e2465',
  barStyle: { backgroundColor: UI_COLORS['foxy'] },
}
  );
```

Now, I can send info between these screens right. HomeScreen, TrendingScreen, ProfileScreen, but the problem I am getting is when I have to open another screen which is not the part of it. How do I navigate to the screen say 'DiffScreen' from any of those screen. i.e. Suppose I am in HomeScreen, and I want to go to 'DiffScreen' which is not the part of the bottomNavigator. Any help, how I can get to that screen? Something like 
`this.props.navigation.navigate('DiffScreen')`  or something like that
 I am just sensing a bit of redux requirement here, but would be better if I could do without it.